# Mono Framework Build Error - Mac OSX

Tags: vb.net, mono, jetbrains-ide, visual-studio-mac, rider

When using the Mono framework 5.10.0.16 (regardless of IDE: VS for Mac, JetBrains Rider and MonoDevelop) the same error occurs and I cannot make sense of it:

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.targets(73, 5): [MSB3883] Unexpected exception: 
Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.targets(73, 5): [null] System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): ApplicationName='vbnc.exe', CommandLine=' /noconfig @"/var/folders/sj/sblgn2q93b1084nm213419f80000gn/T/tmp54fb2d36c21545118516981a1817b134.rsp"', CurrentDirectory='', Native error= Cannot find the specified file
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x002dc] in <f8bb3922e51744d9ace1aa6aedc374ea>:0 
  at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start () [0x0003a] in <f8bb3922e51744d9ace1aa6aedc374ea>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
  at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.ExecuteTool (System.String pathToTool, System.String responseFileCommands, System.String commandLineCommands) [0x000c9] in <0027e94ddd2948b0b937f5e2d51fcfe1>:0 
  at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BuildTasks.ManagedCompiler.ExecuteTool (System.String pathToTool, System.String responseFileCommands, System.String commandLineCommands) [0x00066] in <896b154c97654cea80889fd96e18abdc>:0
```

[image: Visual Representation of the Error]

I have tried installing different versions, the error persists, I'm not sure what to make of it but I notice a `vnbc.exe`

I am using MacOSX version 10.13.4

Comment: `vbnc.exe` is located in the `{MonoFrameworkLocation}/lib/mono/4.5/` and not in the `Commands` directory and thus not in any default path. You can try sym-linking into the `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: @SushiHangover I'm unfamiliar with this concept? please help out

Comment: You might wait till 5.12 lands, http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.12.0/ Visual Basic on Mono is of the lowest priority (behind C# and F#), so at this moment, you'd better switch to Windows and Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue in mono https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/7756. It's already fixed. We are waiting for new release.